# Generalized Method of Moment (GMM) estimation on zoo series

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, zoo, rolling-computation

I have this zoo series.

```
    > str(ALLXbm)
‘zoo’ series from 1998-01-01 to 2017-12-01
  Data: num [1:240, 1:19] 0.00289 0.00992 -0.00424 0.07958 -0.035 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:19] "DE" "DB" "DM" "IE" ...
  Index:  Date[1:240], format: "1998-01-01" "1998-02-01" "1998-03-01" "1998-04-01" "1998-05-01" "1998-06-01" "1998-07-01" ...
```

The followings are the dput() results. The dependent variable is

```
> dput(ALLX$DE)
structure(c(" 0.0028923077", " 0.0099160000", "-0.0042440000", 
" 0.0795800000", "-0.0350041667", "-0.2480500000", " 0.0042880000", 
"-0.1620888889", " 0.0637518519", " 0.0928178571", "-0.0974379310", 
"-0.1012612903", "-0.0141133333", " 0.0373500000", " 0.0420323529", 
" 0.0406323529", "-0.0479314286", " 0.0393514286", " 0.0134594595", 
"-0.0042162162", " 0.0282142857", "-0.0467717949", " 0.0271487179", 
" 0.0484756757", " 0.0388105263", "-0.0232324324", "-0.1534487179", 
"-0.0553538462", "-0.0127976190", " 0.0248613636", "-0.0069093023", 
" 0.0016234043", "-0.0004617021", "-0.0747617021", " 0.0362914894", 
" 0.0773816327", "-0.0038936170", " 0.0876829787", "-0.0198040000", 
"-0.0078372549", " 0.0343978723", " 0.0350833333", "-0.0382480000", 
" 0.0824346939", "-0.0280615385", "-0.0312228070", "-0.1020928571", 
"-0.1011178571", " 0.0460186441", " 0.0407403509", "-0.0200607143", 
" 0.1692310345", " 0.1254927273", "-0.0012947368", " 0.0410393443", 
"-0.0060650000", " 0.1175457627", "-0.0219952381", " 0.0538709677", 
" 0.1302564516", " 0.0177306452", " 0.0465440678", "-0.0318777778", 
"-0.0027257576", "-0.0808714286", " 0.0753223881", " 0.0421338235", 
" 0.0192617647", " 0.0645835821", " 0.0178743243", " 0.0917106667", 
"-0.0504720000", "-0.0605917808", " 0.0670115942", " 0.0841644737", 
"-0.0862937500", " 0.0583458333", " 0.0341283951", " 0.0363376623", 
"-0.0072297619", " 0.0697188235", " 0.0708900000", " 0.0964263736", 
" 0.0265102273", "-0.0310302326", " 0.0419810000", "-0.0719272727", 
" 0.0243521739", "-0.0945943925", " 0.0339018868", " 0.0440350000", 
" 0.0503681818", " 0.0629381356", "-0.0510975000", " 0.0249760684", 
" 0.0827214876", " 0.0892224806", "-0.0168313043", " 0.0291585366", 
" 0.0273647541", "-0.0975674242", "-0.0746062016", " 0.0238595238", 
"-0.0278552000", "-0.0925223077", " 0.0659656934", " 0.0456731343", 
" 0.0466132450", "-0.0135568493", " 0.0414873016", " 0.0340628205", 
" 0.0267903846", "-0.0494906667", " 0.0180333333", " 0.0387062500", 
"-0.0283124183", " 0.0306898810", " 0.0886619048", "-0.0198162921", 
"-0.0154431818", "-0.0838285714", " 0.0658326531", "-0.0614076503", 
" 0.0424984211", "-0.0170115000", " 0.0205202970", " 0.0596765258", 
"-0.0538638298", "-0.0453000000", "-0.0493330317", " 0.0545885714", 
" 0.1193183168", "-0.0335423810", " 0.0599138393", " 0.0207066964", 
" 0.0554773756", " 0.0606587156", " 0.0448098039", "-0.0354082569", 
" 0.0057316038", " 0.0019272727", " 0.0214976303", "-0.0108309179", 
" 0.0166442211", " 0.0028019512", "-0.0548807910", " 0.0297556962", 
"-0.0161016854", " 0.0100739726", " 0.0538203704", " 0.0304168724", 
" 0.0246617647", " 0.0294436975", "-0.0192055300", "-0.0221397906", 
" 0.0429194215", "-0.1356025974", " 0.0155836364", " 0.0421339806", 
" 0.0193581152", "-0.0316510526", " 0.0171187192", " 0.0299633484", 
" 0.0136308017", "-0.0803899225", "-0.0462198413", "-0.0337478469", 
"-0.0044057018", " 0.0297085185", " 0.0273300000", "-0.0814074689", 
" 0.0194720183", "-0.0640064885", " 0.0194782979", " 0.0047418868", 
"-0.0393941634", " 0.0119372093", "-0.0092268116", "-0.0221629956", 
" 0.0803489130", "-0.0976939502", "-0.0391824701", "-0.0672646154", 
"-0.0124784247", "-0.1038085627", "-0.0105592476", "-0.0279538710", 
" 0.0196077181", " 0.0338205788", "-0.0189602996", "-0.0860247273", 
"-0.0478760714", "-0.0510344720", " 0.0275029586", " 0.0428622291", 
" 0.0166286232", "-0.0288036101", "-0.0180476923", " 0.0393909483", 
"-0.0641453901", "-0.0841982143", " 0.0047675900", "-0.0240106312", 
"-0.0700313793", " 0.0733418994", "-0.0533325905", "-0.0331509589", 
" 0.0489809399", "-0.0736352078", " 0.0240526646", "-0.0939243553", 
"-0.0042405995", "-0.0387828042", "-0.0470409756", "-0.0931115294", 
"-0.0910497738", " 0.0013111111", " 0.0348456633", " 0.0705459082", 
" 0.0758425000", "-0.1478202222", " 0.0717040179", " 0.0569382114", 
"-0.0945091623", " 0.1044561713", " 0.0293398396", "-0.1272769802", 
" 0.0325193750", " 0.0277184066", "-0.0341782369", "-0.0250598160", 
" 0.0189187500", "-0.0074535385", "-0.0359813953", " 0.0160150115", 
" 0.0476877551", "-0.1018837398", "-0.0427113689", " 0.0191961637", 
" 0.1059326403"), index = structure(c(883612800, 886291200, 888710400, 
891388800, 893980800, 896659200, 899251200, 901929600, 904608000, 
907200000, 909878400, 912470400, 915148800, 917827200, 920246400, 
922924800, 925516800, 928195200, 930787200, 933465600, 936144000, 
938736000, 941414400, 944006400, 946684800, 949363200, 951868800, 
954547200, 957139200, 959817600, 962409600, 965088000, 967766400, 
970358400, 973036800, 975628800, 978307200, 980985600, 983404800, 
986083200, 988675200, 991353600, 993945600, 996624000, 999302400, 
1001894400, 1004572800, 1007164800, 1009843200, 1012521600, 1014940800, 
1017619200, 1020211200, 1022889600, 1025481600, 1028160000, 1030838400, 
1033430400, 1036108800, 1038700800, 1041379200, 1044057600, 1046476800, 
1049155200, 1051747200, 1054425600, 1057017600, 1059696000, 1062374400, 
1064966400, 1067644800, 1070236800, 1072915200, 1075593600, 1078099200, 
1080777600, 1083369600, 1086048000, 1088640000, 1091318400, 1093996800, 
1096588800, 1099267200, 1101859200, 1104537600, 1107216000, 1109635200, 
1112313600, 1114905600, 1117584000, 1120176000, 1122854400, 1125532800, 
1128124800, 1130803200, 1133395200, 1136073600, 1138752000, 1141171200, 
1143849600, 1146441600, 1149120000, 1151712000, 1154390400, 1157068800, 
1159660800, 1162339200, 1164931200, 1167609600, 1170288000, 1172707200, 
1175385600, 1177977600, 1180656000, 1183248000, 1185926400, 1188604800, 
1191196800, 1193875200, 1196467200, 1199145600, 1201824000, 1204329600, 
1207008000, 1209600000, 1212278400, 1214870400, 1217548800, 1220227200, 
1222819200, 1225497600, 1228089600, 1230768000, 1233446400, 1235865600, 
1238544000, 1241136000, 1243814400, 1246406400, 1249084800, 1251763200, 
1254355200, 1257033600, 1259625600, 1262304000, 1264982400, 1267401600, 
1270080000, 1272672000, 1275350400, 1277942400, 1280620800, 1283299200, 
1285891200, 1288569600, 1291161600, 1293840000, 1296518400, 1298937600, 
1301616000, 1304208000, 1306886400, 1309478400, 1312156800, 1314835200, 
1317427200, 1320105600, 1322697600, 1325376000, 1328054400, 1330560000, 
1333238400, 1335830400, 1338508800, 1341100800, 1343779200, 1346457600, 
1349049600, 1351728000, 1354320000, 1356998400, 1359676800, 1362096000, 
1364774400, 1367366400, 1370044800, 1372636800, 1375315200, 1377993600, 
1380585600, 1383264000, 1385856000, 1388534400, 1391212800, 1393632000, 
1396310400, 1398902400, 1401580800, 1404172800, 1406851200, 1409529600, 
1412121600, 1414800000, 1417392000, 1420070400, 1422748800, 1425168000, 
1427846400, 1430438400, 1433116800, 1435708800, 1438387200, 1441065600, 
1443657600, 1446336000, 1448928000, 1451606400, 1454284800, 1456790400, 
1459468800, 1462060800, 1464739200, 1467331200, 1470009600, 1472688000, 
1475280000, 1477958400, 1480550400, 1483228800, 1485907200, 1488326400, 
1491004800, 1493596800, 1496275200, 1498867200, 1501545600, 1504224000, 
1506816000, 1509494400, 1512086400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", .Dim = c(240L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "DE"))
```

and the independent variable dput() is

```
    > dput(ALLX$SMB_L)
structure(c("-0.0465320170", "-0.0697526439", " 0.0273518415", 
"-0.0740531793", " 0.0316742119", " 0.0152537452", "-0.0264616225", 
" 0.0288440266", "-0.1158052743", "-0.1629207669", "-0.0321036909", 
"-0.0155047450", "-0.0826901559", "-0.0958867805", "-0.1071221681", 
"-0.0448685814", "-0.0246406184", "-0.1212194655", "-0.0753136163", 
" 0.0410887618", "-0.0472807197", "-0.0821359482", "-0.0538328997", 
"-0.1193170755", " 0.0451348940", "-0.0666430865", " 0.1030261973", 
"-0.0512679603", "-0.0858501881", "-0.1100767741", " 0.2831559983", 
" 0.0049661923", "-0.0466122487", "-0.0566777104", "-0.0268275721", 
"-0.0592022576", " 0.0095647556", "-0.0369526728", "-0.0246719322", 
" 0.0051186559", "-0.0462739541", "-0.1027257463", " 0.0041844398", 
"-0.0443327227", " 0.0513661492", "-0.0672995604", "-0.0509956017", 
"-0.0377391126", " 0.1208954628", " 0.0656631973", "-0.0109091553", 
"-0.0319298318", " 0.0762361370", " 0.0082987739", " 0.0744911252", 
" 0.0268991873", " 0.0106712270", "-0.0162705327", "-0.0030339799", 
" 0.0437060161", "-0.0484248103", "-0.0131028206", "-0.0551732558", 
"-0.0827144280", " 0.0412271313", "-0.0625801905", "-0.0531687861", 
"-0.0194387563", " 0.0651252536", " 0.0185203178", " 0.0212495415", 
"-0.0058409877", " 0.0005737324", " 0.0033661115", " 0.0166057656", 
" 0.0273215778", "-0.0160116096", "-0.0516442850", " 0.0622634418", 
" 0.0059385646", "-0.1501443652", " 0.0901923236", " 0.0033375512", 
"-0.0753535560", " 0.0112127728", " 0.0174845326", " 0.0523481171", 
"-0.0687008257", " 0.0364307873", " 0.0136230636", " 0.0058142113", 
" 0.0554519027", " 0.0519022715", "-0.0570389442", "-0.0170328466", 
" 0.0497557753", "-0.0022714909", " 0.0319902902", " 0.0567367912", 
"-0.0807706219", " 0.0858961234", " 0.0222949488", " 0.0242892126", 
" 0.0215915873", " 0.0537398523", "-0.0632469276", " 0.0111250970", 
" 0.0532290206", "-0.0146115567", "-0.0497947429", "-0.0261614454", 
"-0.0231347005", " 0.1003858901", " 0.0445487378", "-0.0150134676", 
"-0.0457789040", "-0.0034933110", "-0.0668239816", "-0.0159024243", 
"-0.0077140317", " 3.6823096028", "-0.0901045024", "-0.0143629036", 
"-0.0098836289", "-0.0311347099", "-0.0151321886", "-0.0233462522", 
"-0.0458991158", "-0.0282613742", "-0.0779876682", " 0.0117855889", 
"-0.0893392649", "-0.0328418515", "-0.0090601777", "-0.0322611560", 
"-0.0641631336", "-0.0595636188", " 0.0206379342", "-0.0891543562", 
" 0.0717742257", "-0.0461537130", "-0.0954444539", "-0.0543154861", 
"-0.0714790350", " 0.0474770475", "-0.0037168520", "-0.0077110744", 
"-0.0355079545", " 0.0354765095", "-0.0152485350", "-0.0037694163", 
" 0.0088693973", "-0.0013576659", "-0.0158975649", "-0.0569949742", 
"-0.0047187899", " 0.0359832832", " 0.0048156392", "-0.0213823507", 
"-0.0253481502", "-0.0305909946", "-0.0459944589", " 0.0697664274", 
"-0.0053565569", " 0.0119311291", "-0.0068067904", "-0.0046527312", 
"-0.0317481424", " 0.0322190631", " 0.0095508469", " 0.0009492415", 
" 0.0109837401", " 0.0129883296", "-0.0230918819", " 0.0291994624", 
" 0.0053826778", " 0.0116937939", " 0.7079728243", " 0.0103552944", 
" 0.0016701093", " 0.0283116307", " 0.0367686262", " 0.0352952954", 
" 0.0251452293", " 0.6522285618", " 0.0005676648", "-0.0355068478", 
" 0.0383934967", "-0.0054156326", "-0.0288061771", " 0.0076047198", 
"-0.0261335344", " 0.0587687305", " 0.0635220884", "-0.0035395762", 
" 0.0638110053", "-0.0043276134", "-0.0183498085", "-0.0306437649", 
"-0.0153833213", " 0.0165571651", "-0.0014514427", "-0.0111594992", 
" 0.0061678879", "-0.0898811021", "-0.0106517096", " 0.0582380903", 
" 0.0471135599", " 0.0946734825", " 0.0518059714", " 0.0075574758", 
" 0.0078389969", " 0.0998944849", "-0.0259425031", "-0.0031939886", 
"-0.0078991041", "-0.0583307843", "-0.0664592297", "-0.0428550515", 
"-0.0282970576", " 0.0085063220", " 0.0027516516", "-0.0413816309", 
"-0.0080472825", " 0.0001809490", "-0.0719654720", " 0.0250187336", 
" 0.0017591069", "-0.0352040828", " 0.0032731177", "-0.0182234806", 
"-0.0276918415", " 0.0246782744", " 0.0390556980", "-0.0240913343", 
"-0.0207629243", " 0.0289632858", "-0.0398579730", " 0.0048926744", 
"-0.0397687581"), index = structure(c(883612800, 886291200, 888710400, 
891388800, 893980800, 896659200, 899251200, 901929600, 904608000, 
907200000, 909878400, 912470400, 915148800, 917827200, 920246400, 
922924800, 925516800, 928195200, 930787200, 933465600, 936144000, 
938736000, 941414400, 944006400, 946684800, 949363200, 951868800, 
954547200, 957139200, 959817600, 962409600, 965088000, 967766400, 
970358400, 973036800, 975628800, 978307200, 980985600, 983404800, 
986083200, 988675200, 991353600, 993945600, 996624000, 999302400, 
1001894400, 1004572800, 1007164800, 1009843200, 1012521600, 1014940800, 
1017619200, 1020211200, 1022889600, 1025481600, 1028160000, 1030838400, 
1033430400, 1036108800, 1038700800, 1041379200, 1044057600, 1046476800, 
1049155200, 1051747200, 1054425600, 1057017600, 1059696000, 1062374400, 
1064966400, 1067644800, 1070236800, 1072915200, 1075593600, 1078099200, 
1080777600, 1083369600, 1086048000, 1088640000, 1091318400, 1093996800, 
1096588800, 1099267200, 1101859200, 1104537600, 1107216000, 1109635200, 
1112313600, 1114905600, 1117584000, 1120176000, 1122854400, 1125532800, 
1128124800, 1130803200, 1133395200, 1136073600, 1138752000, 1141171200, 
1143849600, 1146441600, 1149120000, 1151712000, 1154390400, 1157068800, 
1159660800, 1162339200, 1164931200, 1167609600, 1170288000, 1172707200, 
1175385600, 1177977600, 1180656000, 1183248000, 1185926400, 1188604800, 
1191196800, 1193875200, 1196467200, 1199145600, 1201824000, 1204329600, 
1207008000, 1209600000, 1212278400, 1214870400, 1217548800, 1220227200, 
1222819200, 1225497600, 1228089600, 1230768000, 1233446400, 1235865600, 
1238544000, 1241136000, 1243814400, 1246406400, 1249084800, 1251763200, 
1254355200, 1257033600, 1259625600, 1262304000, 1264982400, 1267401600, 
1270080000, 1272672000, 1275350400, 1277942400, 1280620800, 1283299200, 
1285891200, 1288569600, 1291161600, 1293840000, 1296518400, 1298937600, 
1301616000, 1304208000, 1306886400, 1309478400, 1312156800, 1314835200, 
1317427200, 1320105600, 1322697600, 1325376000, 1328054400, 1330560000, 
1333238400, 1335830400, 1338508800, 1341100800, 1343779200, 1346457600, 
1349049600, 1351728000, 1354320000, 1356998400, 1359676800, 1362096000, 
1364774400, 1367366400, 1370044800, 1372636800, 1375315200, 1377993600, 
1380585600, 1383264000, 1385856000, 1388534400, 1391212800, 1393632000, 
1396310400, 1398902400, 1401580800, 1404172800, 1406851200, 1409529600, 
1412121600, 1414800000, 1417392000, 1420070400, 1422748800, 1425168000, 
1427846400, 1430438400, 1433116800, 1435708800, 1438387200, 1441065600, 
1443657600, 1446336000, 1448928000, 1451606400, 1454284800, 1456790400, 
1459468800, 1462060800, 1464739200, 1467331200, 1470009600, 1472688000, 
1475280000, 1477958400, 1480550400, 1483228800, 1485907200, 1488326400, 
1491004800, 1493596800, 1496275200, 1498867200, 1501545600, 1504224000, 
1506816000, 1509494400, 1512086400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", .Dim = c(240L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "SMB_L"))
```

I wanted a gmm rolling regression and i set up the code below.

```
dogmm <- function(x) {gmm(ALLX$DE~ ALLX$SMB_L, x = ALLXbm)}
kk=rollapply(dogmm, ALLXbm,width=24, by.column = FALSE)
```

Error message is

```
Error in zoo(rval, index(x)[i]) :
 “x” : attempt to define invalid zoo object
```

I really can't figure out even if i spent much time.  when i tried the gmm code alone, it does work
`gmm(ALLXbm$DE~ ALLXbm$SMB_L, x = ALLXbm)`. I'm thinking that, the problem is in the `rollapply` code.  I'm sorry this's my first attempt to GMM. Please some help?